# Internal error when switching workspaces in Eclipse Neon.1

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon

I am receiving the following error each time I click on a menu bar option in Eclipse Neon.1:

`Internal Error: An uncaught exception has been raised. Choose 'Continue' to continue running in an inconsistent state. Choose 'Crash' to halt the application and file a bug report with Crash Reporter. Choosing 'Crash' will result in the loss of all unsaved data.`

When I click on any of the options, the program does not respond. I have to force quit the application in-order for Eclipse to quit.

I am running Mac OS Sierra on my Macbook Pro, 13 inch Retina computer.

I should note that I did not receive this error on OS X El Capitan, or while in OS Sierra's Safe Mode.

I have tried reinstalling Java as well as Eclipse Neon.1 that does not fix it. I tried other version of eclipse, that does not fix it. I have tried reinstalling OS Sierra, that does not fix it as well.

I get the same issue, while accessing the menu bar options of VirtualBox as well as NetBeans.

I know others are not having this issue in OS Sierra, so it is not a Sierra issue, it's most likely an Eclipse issue/bug.

Below is an image of the Error.

[image: Internal Error]